# Add an attribute to html element with javascript on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

What I've tried:

```
function addAttribute(){
     document.getElementById('myid')... 
};
window.onload = addAttribute;
```

How can I add add the attribute to my element with `id="myid"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('telheaderid').yourattribute = "your_value";
```

For instance

```
document.getElementById('telheaderid').value = "your_value";
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#telheaderid').attr('value', 'your_value');
```

EDIT:
Focus is the event that fires up when an element get focused or for instance when we click on the textarea it highlights thats the time.

Using jQuery:

```
$('#telheaderid').focus(function() {
   $(this).val('');
   // run any code when the textarea get focused
});
```

Using plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('telheaderid').addEventListener('focus', function() {
   this.value = "";
});
```

Comment: Try to add this code in javascript console and then try if it works then you must be running this code somewhere wrong

Comment: Or give me the link or access if it's admin side I'll add it

Comment: It works on the console but not if i add it to the header.php, what am i doing wrong? I can see the code there..

Comment: Add this script tag in footer.php just after the body tag ends instead of header.php and try again man! This time I think it would work. And don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: A second method would be to wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){  /* your code here */   });`

Comment: Still not working, there has to be something wrong with the code, im trying to upload a picture for you to imgur but its not resolving.

Comment: Did you try both methods I listed?

Comment: The last one you provided "Using plain javascript" worked on the console, but not if i add the script just before the end of </body> or in the header. This is driving me nuts already.

Comment: I have my site hosted, im replacing the files with FileZilla, and i can see the code in the html. Its there but its not working.

Comment: Dont worry about it, im going to try to ask another question asking why its working on firebug console but not after page load. Thank you im gonna mark it as answered anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById('telheaderid').setAttribute('class','YourAttribute')
```

Comment: But i already can set the class, i need to add an attribute like "OnClick" for example so then i add another function, onClick and i can make it clear the value.

Comment: This works with any Attribute. You can replace the 'class' with e.g. 'onclick','name','style','onblur' etc.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C standard way:

```
function functionAddAttribute(){
     document.getElementById('telheaderid').setAttribute('attributeName', 'attributeValue');
};
window.onload = functionAddAttribute;
```

for IE:

```
function functionAddAttribute(){
     document.getElementById('telheaderid').attributeName = 'attributeValue';
};
window.onload = functionAddAttribute;
```

Enjoy your code!

Comment: Thank you for helping me out but its not working i really dont know why. http://i.imgur.com/Ky5ePUv.png

Comment: you try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/4b4U9/

there is a problem with window.onload function

Comment: Thank you, can you try initializing it with a default value then clearing it with the javascript please?

Comment: Here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/4b4U9/2/

you can use setAttribute o removeAttribute

Comment: Why not? You see the alert box?
The attribute size has blank, or not?
Which browser use? Which version?

Comment: K i managed to make it work, i think i had to add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`before the `<script>` tag, its weird because it was somewhere else on the page and i didn't want to make it redundant.